# How to get custom gmap icon with a local file in vuetify project

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, icons, vuetify.js

I have this bit of code that I can customize with the google maps javascript api:

```
createMarker(map, location, draggable = false) {
return new google.maps.Marker({
  position: location,
  map: map,
  draggable: draggable,
});
```

Everything works with the exception of setting a custom icon image file. As I've found in the past, Vuetify is able to display v-imgs with a remote url but using a local url takes more effort to work properly. Same problem now- I can easily set a remote url like so and the icon appears in my map as intended:

```
createMarker(map, location, draggable = false) {
  return new google.maps.Marker({
  position: location,
  map: map,
  draggable: draggable,
  icon: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Icon-round-Question_mark.svg'
});
```

But using this local url loads up the map without a marker:

```
  icon: 'assets/images/testpin.png',
```

So how am I able to use local image files as a gmap pin icon?

Comment: The only useful case of serving relative paths is when deploying the same code on different domains and you want the one from that domain to load. But even relative ones actually **resolve** to absolute ones. Why do you care how it is passed to the map if it displays correctly?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain clearly but the point is that icon with the local url is *not* passed to the map correctly, that's the problem.

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, you need to use full path for map icons even with local files. Or use the network tab to see what path is being resolved from your relative one.

Comment: If you look in your console when you load that map, you will see it tries to load the icon from a broken path. Adjust your `icon` property so it matches the URL where the icon is placed at. You probably need something like `'/assets/images/testpin.png'` or `'../assets/images/testpin.png'`.